# IOS font - Can I use brand typography for app that will work on IOS?

Tags: ios, font, app

I'm designing an app, that will be supported for Android and Ios. The brand font is Lato. I'm wondering if I should use SF Pro while designing this app or can I use a brand font?

Answer (score 1):

The [Apple HIG guidelines on typography](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) say that it's best to use built-in text styles whenever possible.

This is because Apple's built-in styles will automatically have features like Dynamic Type out-of-the-box. Choosing a built-in style may mean less development effort, as there is less effort spent on customization. In addition, if you implement a built-in style, the UI may be less likely to break with iOS upgrades.

However, you can choose to use a different font instead, and many apps will take that route for a variety of reasons. Some factors to think about could be how it will affect your users, the current and future development cost, and brand alignment.

Ultimately, it's up to you and your team on what font to use.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to that, you will have to read the terms on the usage of the font. It may not be available to be installed on the device. Fonts are tricky things from a legal point of view.